# i have tried to list up titles in an url useing 'for loop' but I do not understand why error code come out

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

below is what I have tried

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?query=%ED%8C%8C%EC%9D%B4%EC%8D%AC&nso=&where=blog&sm=tab_viw.all"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all(class_="api_txt_lines")

for i in title:
    print(i.attrs["title"])
```

error codes as below

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/pycharm_test/crawler/pic.py", line 11, in 
> print(i.attrs["title"])
> KeyError: 'title'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You should use a better format for the question

Comment: `print(i)` will suffice.

Comment: What’s the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

There is no title in your `<a>`, if you wanna print the text use `print(i.get_text())`:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?query=%ED%8C%8C%EC%9D%B4%EC%8D%AC&nso=&where=blog&sm=tab_viw.all"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all(class_="api_txt_lines")

for i in title:
    print(i.get_text())
```